# Not a major error but I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined`. I am not sure what my next move will be

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to make a new command called, "addtags". However, it keeps I keep getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined`. I am not sure what my next move will be. Kindly check the code below. Thank you in advance. Cheers!

```
let msg = await message.channel.send('Creating tag...');

if (!args.join(' ').split('|')[0]) {
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTitle("Error")
      .setDescription("Please provide a name for your tag!");

   return message.channel.send(embed);
  }
if (!args.join(' ').split('|')[1]) {
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTitle("Forbidden")
      .setDescription("Please provide a text for your tag");

   return message.channel.send(embed);
  }

if (!client.tags.has(message.guild.id)) client.tags.set(message.guild.id, {});
if (client.tags.has(message.guild.id, args.join(' ').split('|')[0])) {
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM'])
      .setTitle("Forbidden")
      .setDescription("The tag that you're trying to make already exists");

   return message.channel.send(embed)
 } 

   client.tags.set(message.guild.id, {
   name: args.join(' ').split('|')[0],
   text: args.join(' ').split('|')[1]
   }, args.join(' ').split('|')[0]);

   msg.edit.embed(`Tag created with an ID of: ${message.id}`);
```

Comment: because of `client.tags.has`, maybe `client.tags` is undefined. You can trace everywhere when you need to get the `has` value, feels like `undefined.has()`

Comment: looks like you forgot to add null check.Add null check like `client && client.tags && client.tags.has`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue 

`if (!client.tags.has(message.guild.id)) client.tags.set(message.guild.id, {});`

`!client` that is a falsy thingy. Basically if it does not exists check its tags.